# What's the correct way to implement a user-defined do.call's what function?

Tags: r, do.call

I have a `do.call` use-case (as result of calling `mclapply`) simplified to the following:

```
myfunc <- function(x, y) {
  str(x)
  #return(x + y)
} 

res <- list(list(x=1,y=1),list(x=2,y=2),list(x=3,y=3))
str(res)

do.call(what="myfunc", res)
```

No matter what I do in `myfunc` it never works. I'd expect `do.call` to call `myfunc` three times and pass the resp. x and y but instead it calls it once with all the data and complains it doesn't know what to do with the remaining arguments ... what's the correct way to implement the `what` function such that will apply something over each list element as it does with any other base function?

**UPDATE** What lead to my confusion over the use of `do.call` is that I always saw its use to "reduce" the results of a collection. What I didn't realize is that the functions being called by `do.call` do handle list types and reduce scenarios e.g. `rbind`

Comment: You might be confusing `do.call` and `lapply`. `do.call` treats elements of a list as arguments to a function. It does not loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`lapply` handles the looping, `do.call` applies list elements as arguments. Try this:

```
lapply(res, function(l) do.call('myfunc', l))
```

Answer (score 1):

In `tidyverse`, `walk` + `reduce` can use used

```
library(purrr)
walk(res, reduce, myfunc)
#num 1
#num 2
#num 3
```